# Converting timestamp format in dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

I have read a csv file and made a dataframe where timestamp column is in format "11/12/2020 3:01".

How do I convert this into "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ssssss" format for the data of that particular timestamp column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("timestamp_col",
    date_format(
        unix_timestamp($"timestamp_col", "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm").cast("timestamp"),  
        "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

watch for .strftime in the documentation
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

timestamp.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")

Comment: this is a scala question, not python